# Ace Editor - Autocomplete for custom Keywords not working on "Enter" or "Tab"

Tags: ace-editor

I built a custom completer for ace editor which shows my custom words within the autocomplete popup. However, I am not able to use my newly added suggestions using TAB or ENTER to actually *use* them for autocompletion.

Here is what I did:

```js
    /* options */

    codeEditorOptions: {
      fontSize: 14,
      enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
      enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
      enableSnippets: true,
    },

    // ...

    /* custom Wordlist */

    const suggestions = [
      { name: 'foo' },
      { name: 'bar' },
    ];

    // ...

    /* my own completer */

    const staticWordCompleter = {
      getCompletions(_editor, _session, _pos, _prefix, callback) {
        callback(null, suggestions.map(item => ({
          caption: item.name
          value: item.name
          meta: 'MyOwn',
        })));
      },
    };

    editor.completers.push(staticWordCompleter);
```

the suggestions show up in editor just fine, however, I cannot "select" them, e.g. use arrow keys to navigate to my own suggestion and then use Enter oder Tab to activate the completion. I then tried to enter a custom completer function, like this:

```js
          completer: {
            insertMatch(__editor, data) {
              editor.insert(data.caption);
            },
          },
```

but of course thise now has the effect that if I type "fo" and I want to use the autocomplete for "foo", it then inserts "fofoo" into the editor.

Built-in completers, including local, just work fine and expected. It's just "MyOwn", that does not work. Basically my suggestions show up, I can select them using arrow keys just fine, but when I then use "TAB" or "ENTER" to "execute" the suggestion, the AutoComplete Popup just closes and nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong...?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

Apparently, it was a combination of two things that I missed:

1.) first of all, **ALL** properties of the custom callback need to be filled, e.g.

```
  caption: item.name
  value: item.name
  meta: 'MyOwn'
  score: 100
```

2.) Second, if you have a custom completer function, **you also need to call the parent insertMatch method**:

```
    completer: {
      insertMatch(__editor, data) {
        editor.completer.insertMatch({ value: data.value });
        // own additional code..
      },
    },
```